# System of differential equations - 3 masses spring system

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I've got some problem with solving system of second order differential equations which solves the move of 3 masses at 4 springs - horizontally.

There is no problem with arrranging the equation, it looks like that(masses of each object and stiffness factors are the same for every spring): 
$$ m \frac{d^{2}x_{1}}{dt^{2}} = -2kx_{1} + kx_{2} $$
$$ m \frac{d^{2}x_{2}}{dt^{2}} = -kx_{1} + 2kx_{2} -kx_{3} $$
$$ m \frac{d^{2}x_{3}}{dt^{2}} = -kx_{2} + 2kx_{3} $$

Then i define $\omega ^{2} = \frac{k}{m}$ and divide both sides of all of the equations by $m$:

$$  \frac{d^{2}x_{1}}{dt^{2}} = -2\omega ^{2}x_{1} + \omega ^{2}x_{2} $$
$$  \frac{d^{2}x_{2}}{dt^{2}} = -\omega ^{2}x_{1} + 2\omega ^{2}x_{2} -\omega ^{2}x_{3} $$
$$  \frac{d^{2}x_{3}}{dt^{2}} = -\omega ^{2}x_{2} + 2\omega ^{2}x_{3} $$

I am rewritting it using matrices:
$$ \begin{bmatrix} \ddot{x_{1}}\\\ddot{x_{2}}\\ \ddot{x_{3}} \end{bmatrix} = \omega^{2} \begin{bmatrix} -2 & 1 & 0\\ -1 & 2 & -1\\ 0 & -1 & 2 \end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix} x_{1} \\ x_{2} \\ x_{3} \end{bmatrix}$$

And right there I am stuck.

Comment: Which substituion will work in rewritting it as a system of first order ODEs?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make the Ansatz

$x_i = A_i e^{\Omega t}$ (i=1,2 or 3) and Substitute it into this System. After that you can rewrite this System in a form where a Matrix (this Matrix depends on $\Omega$) Multiplied by the vector $\vec{A} = (A_1,A_2,A_3)^T$ is equal to Zero.

That means you obtain an Eigenvalue Problem; set the determinant of this Matrix to Zero. You will obtain a cubic equation that yields 3 different Solutions. Let these Solutions be denoted by $\Omega_1,\Omega_2,\Omega_3$. To every single solution you can determine the eigenvectors $\vec{A}_1,\vec{A}_2,\vec{A}_3$ (by substituting the corresponding solution into the Matrix and solving the linear algebraic system).

Finally, you can write the solution in the form:

$\vec{x}= (x_1,x_2,x_3)^T = \sum_{i=1}^3 \vec{A}_i e^{\Omega_i t}$.

Comment: I did so: 
$$x_{i} = A_{i} e^{i \omega t }, i=1,2,3$$ then
$$\ddot{x_{i}} = - \omega^{2} A_{i} e^{i \omega t}, i =1,2,3.$$

Dividing by $-\omega^{2}$ leads us to:
$ \begin{bmatrix} A_{1} \\ A_{2} \\ A_{3} \end{bmatrix} e^{i \omega t} = \begin{bmatrix} 2 & -1 & 0 \\ 1 & -2 & 1 \\ 0 & 1 & -2 \end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix} A_{1} \\ A_{2} \\ A_{3} \end{bmatrix} e^{ i \omega t} $ 
which leads me nowhere I guess.

Comment: Ok, so I'm looking now for solution of standard eigenvalue problem $|A - \lambda I | = 0 $, where $ A = \begin{bmatrix} 2 & -1 & 0 \\ 1 & -2 & 1 \\ 0 & 1 & -2 \end{bmatrix} $, but it gives me 2 real and 1 complex eigenvalue with crazy values...

Comment: rewrite $(A_1,A_2,A_3)^T$ as $(1 & 0 & 0 /// 0 & 1 & 0 /// 0 & 0 & 1)  (A_1,A_2,A_3)^T$ (identity Matrix times this vector) and subtract the matrices. (I apologize my lack in Latex knowledge); Moreover you forgot to write the left Hand side of your above comment as $\omega^2 (A_1 A_2 A_3)^T e^{i \omega t}$ (that might be the reason that you got strange eigenvalues).

Comment: $$ \begin{bmatrix} 1 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 & 0  \\ 0 & 0 & 1 \end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix} A_{1} \\ A_{2} \\ A_{3} \end{bmatrix}  e^{i \omega t} = \begin{bmatrix} 2 & -1 & 0 \\ 1 & -2 & 1 \\ 0 & 1 & -2 \end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix} A_{1} \\ A_{2} \\ A_{3} \end{bmatrix} e^{i \omega t} $$
I did so but i still don't see the next step.

Comment: You forgot to write the left Hand side of your recent comment as $\omega^2 I (A_1 A_2 A_3)^T e^{i \omega t}$ where $I$ is shorthand for identity matrix

Comment: I divided both sides by $- \omega^{2} $ so it's proper equation i guess